# Multi file upload in ASP.NET using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a button on my website where users can upload multiple files onto the site. For some reason, in my controller the "file" variable always gets the value of NULL. I am able to upload files as a user, but my controller doesn't read that in for some reason. I'm not sure why and any guidance to the right direction would be greatly appreciated !

This is my cshtml:

```
<p id="FileArea"></p>
<input id="Files" name="Files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

This is my model:

```
public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
```

This is my controller:

```
foreach (var file in viewModel.Candidate.Files)
{
      var file_s = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/location", file_s);
      file_s.SaveAs(path);
}
```

Comment: Post your **rendered** `<form>` element's open-tag. also post your **actual** controller action method's full definition, not just the body.

Comment: In other words, you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mason _Actually_, no - I’m not asking for an MRE - I was asking because I suspect the OP isn’t using the right `enctype`.

Comment: @Dai A proper MRE would show whether they were using the right enctype or not.